# what are dinitrophenyl (DNP) derivatives?

Tags: biochemistry

what are dinitrophenyl (DNP) derivatives? Reading "The Amino-acid Sequence in the Phenylalanyl Chain of Insulin" paper by Sanger (1951). I am not a Biochem major.. yet

Comment: It’s the product of the reaction of an amino acid with fluorodinitro benzene: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Fluoro-2,4-dinitrobenzene

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46359/dinitrophenyl-dnp-derivatives-of-amino-acids-specifically-epsilon-dnp-lysine